# How to use Klaviyo with PWA Studio?

Tags: magento2, redirect, pwa-studio

I did the Klaviyo module setup in my Magento PWA Studio, it gave me all the backend functions, but I was missing the frontend JS scripts, I had to add them via Google Tag Manager.

https://developers.klaviyo.com/en/v1-2/docs/custom-event-tracking

But there's something that Klaviyo support wasn't able to help me with, they have the product IDs and the base URL, so every time I create a campaign with a catalog feed, it set up the product URL, as such, **mystore.com/catalog/product/view/id/123** instead of **mystore.com/myproduct.html**.

https://help.klaviyo.com/hc/en-us/articles/5486899706267-Guide-to-integrating-a-headless-Magento-2-setup#product-catalog5

How could I solve it?
Should I create redirects from PWA Studio to the product URL?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up a redirect, you can use your Google Merchant Feed or an XML export.

https://developers.klaviyo.com/en/v1-2/docs/guide-to-syncing-a-custom-catalog-feed-to-klaviyo

You can adjust your extension configurations to use the PWA Studio public URL instead of the backend Magento URL, Klaviyo will recognize the URL, image, and product details after mapping them.